# Usando ImagemView para carregar foto da galeria

Tags: java, android, galeria

Eu quero fazer um programa que eu carregue uma foto para uma `ImagemView` da galeria do Android.

Preciso de um código para abrir a galeria e salvar a imagem como se fosse para um perfil.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? poste como resposta para ajudar outros usuários!

Comment: http://tjkannan.blogspot.in/2012/01/load-image-from-camera-or-gallery.html http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/20/select-an-image-from-gallery-in-android-and-show-it-in-an-imageview/ Verifique os exemplos destes links e veja se ajuda você assim como outros desenvolvedores que queiram fazer o mesmo.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema com a resposta? Ou precisa de mais alguma informação?

Answer (score 2):

#### Primeiro passo

Dar permissão de leitura usando `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` para fotos da galeria no `manifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

#### Segundo passo

Criar uma simples intenção

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

#### Terceiro passo

Exibir foto na em um `ImageView` explorando o ciclo de vida da aplicação, utilizando o método `onActivityResult()`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }
}
```

Boa sorte!