# Registrando foto em android sem abrir a câmera

Tags: android, android-camera

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em android onde eu preciso que toda vez em que uma pessoa efetue o login o aplicativo registre uma foto e mande junto com a autenticação.

Porem não consigo desenvolver isso sem que a câmera do celular seja ativada, preciso que o aplicativo registre a foto sem ficar ativando a câmera.

Comment: Bom dia amigo, no caso seria para pegar a foto da galeria de fotos ou seja de uma foto ja existente ? poderia explicar melhor, pois se você pretende registrar uma foto sem abrir a camera não consegui entender isso.

Comment: Você quer pegar uma foto da galeria?

Comment: Veja se essa resposta te ajuda Pedro: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/156887/35406

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, você quer tirar uma foto da câmera e salvar automaticamente sem interação alguma do usuário. O android não permite isso sem que haja pelo menos um preview. Até pouco tempo atrás, era possível abrir o preview em uma tela com 1px, mas não sei se ainda funciona.

Comment: Então, o que eu preciso é que ele registre a foto sem abrir a tela da câmera, basicamente sem que o usuário perceba que a foto foi registrada.